# Programmatically set the username and password for my Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I programmatically set the username and password for my Crystal Report?

Comment: Are you talking about the DB username and password?  What version of CR?

Comment: And what language? What method of using Crystal? RDC? Question is presently too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Through the connectioninfo object on the reportdocument is the only way I know of.

Answer (score -1):

go to odbcad32 in command prompt and change the settings there...